# string concatenation is not working as expectred for URL call in PYTHON

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I am trying to extract some dividend data and am having some success.  What I want to do not is have the required string be generated automatically off of a list of Ticker Symbols (IBM, MSFT, GE . . .etc).

The below python code works:

```
import Quandl
divdf=Quandl.get("SEC/DIV_IBM", authtoken="W3P77LRwVFzvFfL9siB4")

divdf.head()

Out[1]:
Date        Dividend    
1962-02-06  0.00100
1962-05-08  0.00100
1962-08-07  0.00100
1962-11-05  0.00100
1963-02-05  0.00133
```

But when I try to create the string inside get() it does not.  Here is the code I have tried:

```
partA=('"SEC/DIV_')
symbol=('IBM"')
authtoken='"W3P77LRwVFzvFfL9siB4"'
totalGrab = partA + symbol + ", authtoken=" + authtoken
```

when I print totalGrab it looks as if it would work because it appears to be identical to the original string . but unfortunately it does not work.

```
In [19]:

print(totalGrab)
"SEC/DIV_IBM", authtoken="W3P77LRwVFzvFfL9siB4"

try1=Quandl.get(totalGrab)
```

gives me this error:

```
ErrorDownloading: Error Downloading! HTTP Error 400: BAD_REQUEST
```

I tried this as well, with no luck:

```
divdf=Quandl.get(partA + symbol, authtoken="W3P77LRwVFzvFfL9siB4")
```

any thoughts on a fix?

thanks much for any attention to this.

John

Comment: `divdf=Quandl.get(partA+symbol, authtoken=authtoken)`?

Comment: NightShadeQueen, I tried that but got a different error message DatasetNotFound: Dataset not found. Check Quandl code: "SEC/DIV_IBM" for errors

Comment: Your quotes are a disaster. You have quote literals inside your strings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Falmarri, but the original required field has quotes, I am unaware of how to print a variable that has quotes in any other way.  What I need is Quandl.get("SEC/DIV_IBM", authtoken="W3P77LRwVFzvFfL9siB4") exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that works:

```
divdf=Quandl.get("SEC/DIV_IBM", authtoken="W3P77LRwVFzvFfL9siB4")
```

the `get()` method takes two arguments: `"SEC/DIV_IBM"` and the `authToken`.

In the example that does not work, you are passing in a single argument, which is a String.

Here's an example to demonstrate what you are doing:

```
a = 2
b = 3
sum(a,b) ## this works

c = "{0}, {1}".format(a,b) ## generates the string "2,3"
sum(c) ## this won't work.
```

Comment: xbonez, I think I adjusted my try using your input (added to my OP) but that did not seem to solve the issue